# Whats going on in this Class Constructor?

Tags: disassembly, x86, c++, address, pointer

meanwhile, I am learning more and more how to reverse engineer. Ive figured out tons of stuff already, but I came to the point, where I just need some little explanation whats going on in the constructor of a specific class.

I know, that this specific class (Class A) inherits 3 other Classes (lets say: class B, class C, class D).
Class A calls the constructors of B,C,D. Everything up to here is clear for me.

But:

Class D has a method "addListener" which points to an attribute (this + 0x34).

(this + 0x34) is assigned in the constructor to a address..

```
int A::A(void *someObject) {
    B::B();
    C::C();

    *this = 0x1f18e8;
    *(this + 0x28) = 0x1f190c;         // whats going here?
    *(this + 0x34) = 0x1f193c;         // and here?

    // Ive seen, that those addressees are inside of the vtable of Class A
    // 
    //     __ZTV12A:        // vtable for A
    // ...
    // 001f18e8         db  0xc6
    // 001f193c         db  0xb0
    // 001f190c         db  0xba
    // ...

    D::D();

    // Some other attributes, but these are clear for me (just 
    // have to name them right, by figuring out where these attributes are used):

    *(this + 0x38) = someObject;
    *(this + 0x3c) = 0x0;
    *(this + 0x50) = 0x0;
    *(this + 0x54) = 0x0;
    *(this + 0x40) = 0xffffffff;
    *(this + 0x44) = 0xffffffff;
    *(this + 0x48) = 0xffffffff;
    *(this + 0x4c) = 0x0;

    D::addListener(this + 0x34);
}
```

Am I right with my conclusion, that D::addListener() adds the class it self to the listener?

In fact I just want to figure out what kind of object is added to the "listener":

```
    D::addListener(this + 0x34);
```

I hope my question is clear enough :)

Comment: Is is the whole constructor ? If not, can you post it ?

Comment: This may be an artifact of multiple inheritance. I found an article which may be useful for understanding this http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear as you first say "Class C has a method "addListerner" which points to an attribute (this + 0x34).", then `D::addListener(this + 0x34);`. Typo?

Also, you should read about (typical) implementations of multiple inheritance. Assume your classes B, C, D have methods `b`, `c`, `d` respectively. A will inherit all of them. Now, if A does *not* override these methods, and anything calls them, they have to be delegated to the correct superclass - the original methods. But these original methods will expect a class layout that corresponds to the original classes. Which means, A needs to "embed" all 3 classes into itself.

Which means A will be laid out like this:

```
+-----+-------------------+
|  00 | vtable of A       |
+-----+-------------------+
|  04 | member 1 of A     |
|  08 | member 2 of A     |
|     | ...               |
+-----+-------------------+
|  28 | vtable of B       |
+-----+-------------------+
|  2c | member 1 of B     |
|  30 | member 2 of B     |
|     | ...               |
+-----+-------------------+
|  34 | vtable of C       |
+-----+-------------------+
|  38 | member 1 of C     |
|  3c | member 2 of C     |
|     | ...               |
+-----+-------------------+
|  ?? | vtable of D       |
+-----+-------------------+
|  ?? | member 1 of D     |
|  ?? | member 2 of D     |
|     | ...               |
+-----+-------------------+
```

So, yes, your conclusion is correct: `D::addListener()` adds the class itself to the listener. But because `D::addListener()` expects a `D`, not an `A`, the thing that's passed isn't the complete `A`, it's just the part of `A` that makes `D`. To make this look exactly like a `D`, it needs its own vtable that looks like a `D` vtable.

But of course, parts of these vtables can be shared. `A` needs all methods in its vtable, so the vtable pointers of the partial classes `B`, `C` and `D` can point to the appropriate part of the `A`s vtable, they don't need their complete own copies.

As to your "what's going on here" questions - these initialize the vtables of the partial classes. (In your assembly listing, you should treat those addresses as arrays of words, not bytes). What i wonder is why there's only 3 of them, there should be 4 for `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Something seems to be confused or omitted here, just like you said "Class C has" first, then used `D::addListener`.

Comment: Ive edited my post, of course it should be D::addListener() instead of C::addListener()

Comment: Something's still wrong as there should be 4 vtables, not 3. Unless one of your classes is really a struct, not a class, that has no methods, not even a constructor. So maybe the offsets, or class names, in my example do not match yours, but the principle still applies.

Comment: What makes me so confused is, I see that addListener accepts an argument of type *Listener... But I can´t see any of the classes inherits *Listener... I am asking where it comes from.

D::addListener(*Listener);

I am expecting that A inherits *Listener.... But Ive checked the *Listener class, which don´t have a constructor, only a destructor.

Comment: I see, B, C, D has constructors. 
    
*(arg_0 + 0x34) = 0x1f193c;

seems to be an object of type *Listener, which don´t have a constructor. Makes the things more confusing for me.

Comment: A doesn't have to (explicitly) inherit from Listener if A inherits from D, and D inherits from Listener. And of course, D may have a constructor even if Listener doesn't. And this would explain why the D part of A is the argument, not A itself.

Comment: Let me check that out, give me a sec... Here is also the disassembled code: http://pastebin.com/E7gNXbxv

Comment: You are right, A inherits from Listener*. So in fact D::addListener(A) happens. But I excepted that Listener* has a virtual method called "notify", which is implemented in Listener*. But "notify" could be existing in Listener* without implementing it, right? (virtual notify(Object*) = 0;)